# Can "deliberation" mean "act consciously"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found the word "deliberation" (and the verb "to deliberate") in a strange context. To explain the behavior of deliberating, the author of the book says:

When you decide to do something, get it done. When you set an appointment with someone show up. When you say “yes,” mean “yes”...

Can "deliberation" mean "act consciously", in this context?
Thank you

Comment: I understand the word "deliberation" used here as an ability to be consistent in doing something, to go through with something one has begun. One of the meanings of this word is 'a slow careful way of doing something'. Apparently, "the careful way" is what is meant here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but could you provide any more context from the text?

You bring up the adverb *consciously*; *deliberately* is effectively a synonym of that - so "act deliberately" *would* be saying the same thing.

But either of these is often used very basically as "on purpose", to clarify that something was not an accident, that "I meant/chose/decided to do that."

And there is less overlap in different forms of the same concepts - e.g. there is not a synonym for *deliberation* that contains *conscious*.

The overlap that is the source of the synonymous adverbs is between the **adjectives** *deliberate* and *conscious*.

***deliberation***, however, is derived from the **verb** *deliberate*, whereas there is no verb form of *conscious*.

I concur with Yulia's comment, that the passage you quoted appears to refer to the 'care' and/or 'thoughtfulness' aspects of *[deliberation](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deliberation)*:

> Thoughtfulness in decision or action.
>
> thoughtful, careful, or lengthy consideration

But I don't think the advice being given in the passage is merely an elaboration of the definition of deliberation; rather it's recommending how you follow through in your various deliberate actions.  In a way it's a suggestion to saturate every detail of your behavior and/or relationships with deliberation.

In this respect, *consciously* would be appropriate, but (as noted above with regard to *deliberately*) it would be less vague to use *[conscientiously](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscientiously)*:

> conscientious:   Thorough and assiduous . . . **careful** and hard-working